# NotAMockException when trying to mock a method on a SpyBean of Environment

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, spybean

In an integration test `(@SpringBootTest)` class I declare a spyBean:

```
@SpyBean
private Environment environment;
```

In a test I try to mock one method:

```
doReturn(true).when(environment).acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("prod"));
```

However, I get the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

How can I properly mock the method?

Comment: Have you tried `Mockito.when(environment.acceptsProfiles(Profiles.of("prod"))).thenReturn(true);` ?

Comment: yeah, same problem.

Comment: did you initialize `environment` properly?

Comment: what annotations do you have on the top of your class? @ SpyBean is a spring annotation, you need @ SpringBootTest annotation, to build the application context for the test.

Comment: how? shouldnt it come from the application context?

Comment: it is a spring boot test- I have added the information to the question to clarify

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment` is part of the essential configuration used to create Spring context while the application is started. The environment object is created before the context is prepared and only later registered as a bean within the context to enable injection. Because of that it cannot be mocked or spied on, similarly to `ApplicationContext` or `BeanFactory`, which are basic Spring context building blocks as well.

You can verify that yourself, using a debugger and the Spring Boot open-sourced code - look specifically at [this part](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication.java#L306-L311) (`run` method in the `SpringApplication` class). The `Environment` object is prepared before the context is created and the mock/spy beans are created and injected during context refresh after its creation. To verify that you could simply create a class, mark it with the `@SpyBean` annotation in a test, set a breakpoint in the constructor and run the test with debugging. Whether Spring testing library should inform about the incorrect usage of `@MockBean`/`@SpyBean` on the interfaces/classes that cannot be mocked or spied on is a different matter and you could ask that question or propose adding that in an appropriate GitHub repository.

Regarding the solution to the problem (I think) you're trying to solve: it looks like you could use the [@ActiveProfiles](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/test/context/ActiveProfiles.html) annotation to enable a specific profile in your test class or use [any other way of setting an active Spring profile](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-profiles#set-profiles).

Comment: thank you for your answer! My problem is, I di not actually want to use settings from the profile in the test, I only want to verify that specific functionality works only if a profile is active.

Comment: Is the functionality based on choosing different beans for injection depending on the profile? This knowledge is required to solve your problem fully, because beans creation takes place on context initialization/refresh, which occurs before running the test case (or even whole test class, depending on the configuration).

Comment: well there is something in the code like if (environment.acceptsProfiles(...)) {someBean.doThis();} else {throw Exception(...)}. I need a way to verify the behaviour in an integrative test without actually using the settings from the "prod" profile.

Comment: If you'd like to test just the `if` (BTW you should consider using different strategies as beans created based on a profile and injected depending on the profile value), it would be best to just stick to a unit test (without Spring context) with mocked `environment`. If it is an integration test, then using a profile has its other consequences like settings and beans. To work around that you could create an additional profile like `test` and skip the settings/beans you do not need if it's active and activate both `prod` and `test` profiles in the test.