# Partially mock a Spring bean when tests run

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, mockito

My Spring Boot v3.2.0 app contains a bean of type `LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean`. When the tests run, I want the `destroy` method of this bean (defined in the parent class `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean`) to do nothing. I attempted to achieve this with

```java
import static org.mockito.Mockito.doNothing;
// other imports omitted

@SpringBootTest
public class MyIntegrationTests {

    @SpyBean
    private AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean;

    @Test
    void myIntegrationTest() {
        doNothing().when(entityManagerFactoryBean).destroy();
        // remainder of test omitted     
    }
}
```

But when I run the test, I get this error which indicates that a spy is not being created for `entityManagerFactoryBean`

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
```

Even if this solution did work, I wouldn't be entirely satisfied with it because there's no obvious way to reuse it in other integration test classes (other than copy-pasting).

Is there another way I can stub the `destroy` method of this bean when the tests run?

### Minimal Reproducible Example

The problem can be reproduced by cloning [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/donalmurtagh/spring-boot-example) and running `./gradlew test`

Comment: This should work as per [mockito's documentation (`site.mockito.org`)](https://site.mockito.org/javadoc/current/org/mockito/Mockito.html#16). Do you have a [MRE], e.g. in form of a github repository?

Comment: @Turing85 Here's a minimal reproducible example https://github.com/donalmurtagh/spring-boot-example

Comment: [This question (`stackoverflow.com`) and its answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76381417/notamockexception-when-trying-to-mock-a-method-on-a-spybean-of-environment) might be related. We can construct the spy manually by `@Autowire`ing instead of `@SpyMock`, and create the spy manually within the test method: `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean emfSpy = spy(entityManagerFactoryBean);`. Here is a [`gist.github.com`](https://gist.github.com/turing85/004f6d96e4a68af4007c326e1d8cb3e0) of the updated version.

Comment: @Turing85 this won't have any effect on the bean in the application context

Answer (score 1):

This has to do with how Spring instantiates the `EntityManagerFactory`. You'll have to use something like this:

```java
@SpyBean(name = "entityManagerFactory", classes = EntityManagerFactory.class)
private Object entityManagerFactoryBean;
```

Unfortunately you'll find that the runtime type of the bean is a proxy that doesn't extend `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean` (see `AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean::createEntityManagerFactoryProxy`). And accessing the proxy's delegate field involves opening internal modules, which isn't such a good idea.

So instead, I suggest wrapping the existing `EntityManagerFactory` in a proxy and intercepting the `destroy()` method. For this, either use lombok with `@Delegate` to avoid writing every delegating method manually, or use CGLib to generate a dynamic proxy over a class (see below). Adding the following in your test class does what you want:

```java
@TestConfiguration
static class Config {
    @Bean
    BeanPostProcessor beanPostProcessor() {
        return new BeanPostProcessor() {
            @Override
            public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) throws BeansException {
                if (bean instanceof AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean) {
                    return Enhancer.create(bean.getClass(),
                        (InvocationHandler) (proxy, method, args) -> {
                            if (method.getName().equals("destroy")) {
                                System.out.println("not destroying!");
                                return null;
                            } else {
                                return method.invoke(factoryBean, args);
                            }
                        });
                }

                return bean;
            }
        };
    }
}
```